# Adding Sequence Flow to BPMN2 Editor

Tags: eclipse-gef

I am developing BPMN2 Editor using GEF. I have BPMN2 EMF Models. When I add SequcenFlow to My Editor it creates fine,But after that  I cant able to any more BPMN Shapes in GEF Editor. I got Exception in IndexOutOfBoundsException in that processing getContentPane().add(child, index).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why are you using `getContentPane()`? your children should be added to the model which is then read by the framework. Can you post some code?

Comment: Hello Vainolo, Thanks for your reply. I haven't used getContentPane().add(child,index). I added to the model only. getContentPane() this are internal processing of AbstractGraphicalEditPart class. The following will be my code for adding SequenceFlow to Process.                                 final SequenceFlow sequenceFlow = Bpmn2Factory.eINSTANCE
    .createSequenceFlow();                                               process.getFlowElements().add(sequenceFlow);

Comment: Hello Vainolo, Thanks for your reply. I fixed that issue. I forget to remove connections from EditParts, getModelChildren() Method. I got this idea after seeing your tutorial closely. Thanks a lot.Can you post Some Tutorials for Properties View and Tabbed Properties View.

Comment: Hello Vainolo, We will expecting soon your properties view tutorials.

Comment: Hello Vainolo, Thanks for your properties view tutorial.